# Xamarin iOS singleton property from binding always return null on real device

Tags: ios, xamarin, binding, device, objective-sharpie

I have created binding for our SDK, it contains singleton property which we use to access all methods and properties of SDK. When I created it as a binding for Xamarin it works fine at simulators, but singleton properties always return null when I run it on real device.
When I do lipo -info for .a static library I got: Architectures in the fat file: libAppoxeeSDKUniversal.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64

iOS 14.4 is installed on real device.
What can be reason why it doesn't work on real device?

Comment: Hi there, not an easy question to answer. Just guessing. Are you using Linking while compiling for device? Try to run your app disabling Linking in your project to be sure compiler is not removing anything.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was main problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with linking. When I change at linkwith.cs file for corresponding .a library SmartLink property to false, it works on real device also. After all my linkwith.cs file looks like:

[assembly: LinkWith ("libAppoxeeInappUniversal.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Simulator|LinkTarget.Arm64, SmartLink = false, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks = "WebKit")]